# replace image using converters in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to change `Image` source dynamically based on the data download using `Converters` in `Xamarin.Forms`

There are total three states of fetching data from the server

1) success when data is downloaded successfully
2) error when data is not downloaded and there is an error
3) when process is idle

for all above cases i am using different icon.

here is my XAMLcode

```
 <Image Source="{Binding CustomerState,  Converter={StaticResource SyncConverter}}"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="20" Margin="8,12,8,12" />
```

here is my converter code

```
public class SyncConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool? syncState = value as bool?;

            if (syncState != null) { 
                if (syncState.Value) return "ic_success";
                else return "ic_error";
            }

          return "ic_idle";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

in above code if `CustomeState` is null then display `ic_idle` icon and if `CuswtomerStat` is true then show success otherwise error.

my view model code

```
private bool? isCustomerState;

public bool? CustomerState
        {
            get { return isCustomerState; }
            set
            {
                isCustomerState = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CustomerState");


            }
        }
```

but somehow xamarin is throwing error at `get { return isCustomerState; }`and the error is

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try to verify "value" before use it. Something like

```
public class SyncConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

          if(value != null){
            bool? syncState = value as bool?;

            if (syncState != null) { 
                if (syncState.Value) return "ic_success";
                else return "ic_error";
            }
           }
          return "ic_idle";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: still getting the same error , if i set `private bool? isCustomerState =false` then i doesnt throw but in this case it shows ic_error rather than ic_status

Comment: Do i need to use DataTrigger for this or converter would be enough

Comment: the issue seems with the `IsVisible="{Binding MasterState}` field when MasterStates goes null IsVisible doesnt know what to do , what say

Comment: Why "IsVisible"? You should bind Source. Then MasterState should not be null for IsVisible. If it could be null, use a IValueConverter to convert from a nullable value to True of False

Answer (score 0):

***Update:*** *As mentioned by Alessandro in the comments - the return type of instance provided by converter might not be the actual issue in this case. The [ImageSourceConverter](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/e6d5186c8acbf37b877c7ca3c77a378352a3743d/Xamarin.Forms.Core/ImageSource.cs) should handle the conversion from string to ImageSource.*

As you are binding to the Source property on the [Image](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Image/) which is of type [ImageSource](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Image/#Public_Fields) - so your converter should also return an instance of [ImageSource](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource/) type.

```
public class SyncConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

      if(value != null){
        bool? syncState = value as bool?;

        if (syncState != null) { 
            if (syncState.Value) return ConvertToImageSource("ic_success");
            else return ConvertToImageSource("ic_error");
        }
       }
      return ConvertToImageSource("ic_idle");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private ImageSource ConvertToImageSource(string fileName)
    {
         return Device.OnPlatform(
              iOS: ImageSource.FromFile($"Images/{fileName}"),
              Android:  ImageSource.FromFile(fileName),
              WinPhone: ImageSource.FromFile($"Images/{fileName}"));
    }
}
```

You can find more details here: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Image_and_ImageSource

Comment: It can return also a string

Comment: Yes - you are right. The TypeConverter on the binding property should take care of the conversion from string to ImageSource.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class SyncConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType != typeof(bool))
                return ConvertToImageSource("ic_idle"); 

            return (bool)value? ConvertToImageSource("ic_success"): ConvertToImageSource("ic_error");
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (bool)value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This won't work. You've misunderstood what `targetType` is. This also isn't the way to detect `null` in C#.